# tikz arrow direction problem in flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

The flowchart is almost what I want, but I am having a problem getting the arrow head to point in the correct direction in one of the paths that has turns in it.  The picture shows the problem, and the code I used to generated looks good, it just doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?  I want to really understand the fix and not just fix this one flowchart, since I have to typeset many flowcharts for a manual.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [draw, rounded rectangle, text centered, draw=black,thick]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text centered]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, text centered, draw=black,thick]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, text centered, draw=black,thick]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [-{Stealth[scale=1.2]},rounded corners,thick]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (io1) [io,below=0.5 of start] {Read $R$};
\node (box1) [process,below=0.5 of io1] {$X \gets 0$};
\node (branch1) [decision,aspect=2,below=0.7 of box1] {$X > R-1$};
\node (return) [startstop,left=1 of branch1] {Return};
\node (box2) [process,below=0.7 of branch1] {$C \gets 0$};
\node (branch2) [decision,below=0.7 of box2] {$C > 2$};
\node (box3) [process,right=1 of branch2] {$X \gets X+1$};
\node (io2) [io,below=0.7 of branch2] {Read $A_{X,C}$};
\node (box4) [process,below=0.7 of io2] {$C \gets C+1$};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (io1);
\draw [arrow] (io1) -- (box1);
\draw [arrow] (box1) -- coordinate[midway](m1)(branch1);
\draw [arrow] (branch1) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m3)(box2);
\node [black,right=0.1 of m3] {False};
\draw [arrow] (branch1) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m4)(return);
\node [black,above=0.1 of m4] {True};
\draw [arrow] (box2) -- coordinate[midway](m2)(branch2);
\draw [arrow] (branch2) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m5)(io2);
\node [black,right=0.1 of m5] {False};
\draw [arrow] (branch2) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m6)(box3);
\node [black,above=0.1 of m6] {True};
\draw [arrow] (io2) -- (box4);
\draw [arrow] (box4) |- ++(0,-1) -| ++(-2.5,0) |- ([xshift=-2.5]m2) -- (m2.west);
\draw [arrow] (box3) |- (m1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot compile this MWE, I get an error related to  [io,below=0.5 of start]

Comment: On ubuntu 15.10/amd64, the file is sad.tex and I do latex sad.tex twice, then dvipdf sad.dvi, and finally view with mupdf sad.pdf

Comment: Just replace `|-([xshift=-2.5]m2) -- (m2.west)` with `|-(m2)`.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of

```
\draw [arrow] (box4) |- ++(0,-1) -| ++(-2.5,0) |- ([xshift=-2.5]m2) -- (m2.west);
```

use

```
\draw [arrow] (box4) |- + (-2.5,-1) |- (m2);
```

Cause of wrong arrow direction is incorrect use of `|-` in arrow path.

**Upgrade:**
Complete code, with corrected errors in it and simplified is:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                    chains,
                    positioning,
                    shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance= 7mm and 13 mm,
     start chain = going below,
     base/.style = {draw, thick, align=center, 
                    inner ysep=1mm, inner xsep=2mm,
                    join=by arrow, on chain},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded rectangle},
       io/.style = {trapezium, base,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
  process/.style = {base},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5, base, inner xsep=0pt},
    arrow/.style = {-{Stealth[scale=1.2]}, rounded corners, thick}
                    ]
 % main
\node (start)   [startstop] {Start};
\node (io1)     [io]        {Read $R$};
\node (box1)    [process]   {$X \gets 0$};
\node (branch1) [decision]  {$X > R-1$};
\node (box2)    [process]   {$C \gets 0$};
\node (branch2) [decision]  {$C > 2$};
\node (io2)     [io]        {Read $A_{X,C}$};
\node (box4) [process,below=0.7 of io2] {$C \gets C+1$};
% left and right
\node (return)  [startstop,left=1 of branch1,reset join] {Return};
\node (box3)    [process, right=1 of branch2,reset join] {$X \gets X+1$};
% coordinates
\node (return)  [startstop,left=of branch1,reset join] {Return};
\node (box3)    [process, right=of branch2,reset join] {$X \gets X+1$};

\draw [arrow] (box1) -- coordinate[midway](m1)(branch1);
\draw [arrow] (box2) -- coordinate[midway](m2)(branch2);

\draw[arrow] (branch2.east) node[above right] {True} -- (box3);
%
\draw[arrow] (branch1.west) node[above left] {True} -- (return);
\node[below right] at (branch1.south) {False};
%
\draw[arrow] (box3) |- (m1);
\draw[arrow] (box4) |- + (-2.5,-1) |- (m2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

Main changes in code:

- the connection between nodes is done by `join` parameter in `base` style.
- for two nodes, where use of `join` parameter is not desired, are set on the end of "main" nodes and use macro `reset join` defined in the preamble of MWE
- replace obsolete `\tikzstyle{ ...}` (now are recommended `\tikzset{...}` with styles written as option of `tikzpicture`

Comment: In the MWE there is an error, instead of `text cent` you will place `text centered]`.

Comment: @salimbou, thank you for info. I also have problems with some nodes, which not show up as it can be seen from provided picture. I will manage this soon.

Comment: I also have the same problem nodes `io1` and  `io2`  have no frames?

Comment: I think  key `draw` must be added to `io` style.

Comment: Meanwhile I succeed to rewrote MWE in question. See, if you like approach used in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

- I simply eliminated `([xshift=-2.5]m2) --`, since `|-` should arrive in the last point, `(m2)`.
- Anyway I think `\tikzstyle{io}` is incomplete. **EDIT:** The `draw=black,thick` options were missing.
- Furthermore I had to load `petri` library.

The MWE is the following.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,arrows.meta,petri}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [draw, rounded rectangle, text centered, draw=black,thick]
\tikzstyle{io} = [draw=black,thick,trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,text centered]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, text centered, draw=black,thick]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, text centered, draw=black,thick]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [-{Stealth[scale=1.2]},rounded corners,thick]
\tikzstyle{arrow2} = [{Stealth[scale=1.2]}-,rounded corners,thick]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (io1) [io,below=0.5 of start] {Read $R$};
\node (box1) [process,below=0.5 of io1] {$X \gets 0$};
\node (branch1) [decision,aspect=2,below=0.7 of box1] {$X > R-1$};
\node (return) [startstop,left=1 of branch1] {Return};
\node (box2) [process,below=0.7 of branch1] {$C \gets 0$};
\node (branch2) [decision,below=0.7 of box2] {$C > 2$};
\node (box3) [process,right=1 of branch2] {$X \gets X+1$};
\node (io2) [io,below=0.7 of branch2] {Read $A_{X,C}$};
\node (box4) [process,below=0.7 of io2] {$C \gets C+1$};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (io1);
\draw [arrow] (io1) -- (box1);
\draw [arrow] (box1) -- coordinate[midway](m1)(branch1);
\draw [arrow] (branch1) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m3)(box2);
\node [black,right=0.1 of m3] {False};
\draw [arrow] (branch1) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m4)(return);
\node [black,above=0.1 of m4] {True};
\draw [arrow] (box2) -- coordinate[midway](m2)(branch2);
\draw [arrow] (branch2) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m5)(io2);
\node [black,right=0.1 of m5] {False};
\draw [arrow] (branch2) -- coordinate[pos=0.4](m6)(box3);
\node [black,above=0.1 of m6] {True};
\draw [arrow] (io2) -- (box4);
\draw [arrow] (box4) |- ++(0,-1) -| ++(-2.5,0) |- (m2);
\draw [arrow] (box3) |- (m1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```